# EF core, incorrect mapping of null for nvarchar

Tags: entity-framework-core

In my ModelBuilder I have this mapping:

```
entity.Property(e => e.topic)
      .HasColumnType("nvarchar(50)")
      .HasColumnName("topic");
```

For this field:

```
public string topic { get; set; }
```

But when I query the table containing column "topic" (same for all column of type nvarchar in every model), the DB value null is mapped with string "null" not with value null.

Is that a bug in EF core? Or am I wrongly mapping the column?

---

**UPDATE**

Here is the actual code:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Bait_dom>(entity =>
  {
    entity.HasKey(e => e.blid)
        .HasName("PK_seo_lb_dom");

    entity.ToTable("bait_dom");

    entity.Property(e => e.blid)
        .HasColumnName("blid");

    entity.Property(e => e.customerid)
      .IsRequired()
      .HasColumnName("customerid")
      .HasMaxLength(50);

    entity.Property(e => e.url)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("url")
            .HasMaxLength(100);

    entity.Property(e => e.mozda)
      .HasColumnName("mozda");

    entity.Property(e => e.kwpos)
      .HasColumnName("kwpos");

    entity.Property(e => e.moztrust)
      .HasColumnName("moztrust");

    entity.Property(e => e.ahrefdr)
      .HasColumnName("ahrefdr");

    entity.Property(e => e.topic)
      .HasColumnType("nvarchar(50)")
      .HasColumnName("topic");

    entity.Property(e => e.status)
      .HasColumnName("status")
      .HasMaxLength(10);

    entity.Property(e => e.createdon)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("createdon");

    entity.Property(e => e.updatedon)
        .HasColumnName("updatedon");
  });

public virtual DbSet<Bait_dom> Bait_dom { get; set; }

public class Bait_dom
{
    public int blid { get; set; }
    public string customerid { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public decimal? mozda { get; set; }
    public int? kwpos { get; set; }
    public decimal? moztrust { get; set; }
    public decimal? ahrefdr { get; set; }
    public string topic { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? askedon { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdon { get; set; }
    public DateTime? updatedon { get; set; }
}
```

Here the table definition:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bait_dom](
    [blid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [customerid] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [url] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [mozda] [numeric](5, 2) NULL,
    [kwpos] [int] NULL,
    [moztrust] [numeric](4, 2) NULL,
    [ahrefdr] [numeric](4, 2) NULL,
    [topic] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [status] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [askedon] [date] NULL,
    [createdon] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [updatedon] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_seo_lb_dom] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[blid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

And finally a query:

```
  List<SiteData> ret = (from d in _db.Bait_dom
           join li in _db.Bait_links on new { d.url, d.customerid } equals new { li.url, li.customerid } into lin
           from l in lin.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where d.customerid == _user.guid
           group new { d, l } by d into dl
           select new SiteData
           {
             dom = dl.Key,
             links = dl.Where(l => l.l != null).Select(l => l.l).ToList(),
             hm = dl.Where(l => l.l != null).Count(l => l.l.status != "planned"),
             hmp = dl.Where(l => l.l != null).Count(l => l.l.status == "planned"),

             asked = dl.Key.askedon,
             lastLink = dl.Where(l => l.l != null && l.l.status != "planned").Max(l => l.l.publishedon),
             nextLink = dl.Where(l => l.l != null && l.l.status == "planned").Min(l => l.l.publishedon)

           })
          .ToList();
```

Comment: What happens if you change the mapping to simply `modelBuilder.Entity<YourType>().Property(e => e.topic).HasMaxLength(50);` (https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/max-length.html) and let convention take care of the rest?

Comment: Can you provide a full example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @MikeBrind tried, didn't change the result.

Comment: @IvanStoev it's rather simple to reproduce it, just create a table with a column nvarchar(50), add it to the context and query it.

Comment: I've tried before asking, but couldn't reproduce. What is `entity` in this line `entity.Property`? I've used `modelBuilder.Entity<TestEntity>()`, is that correct?

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry, I am updating the question with the actual code.

Comment: @IvanStoev hope it's useful, I didn't add all the class definitions I know